# Other Save Button not Disabled when clicked

Tags: javascript

My Problem is that the save button below when clicked is not disabled for processing, unlike above that when it is clicked it will be disabled and will enabled if found missing field that needs to be filled and will just process if requirements are satisfied. so what i want is that either of them are clicked it will disabled both of them for a while while processing

I have this dynamic button where class is below

```
public  class OpportunityCustomCloneController {

public Id oppId {get; set;}
public Id recordTypeId {get; set;}
public Opportunity opp {get;set;}
public String cloneOption {get;set;}
public String pageLayoutFields {get; set;}
public List<String> addFields {get; set;}
public List<LayoutComponent__c> sectionComponent {get;set;}
public Map<Id, List<LayoutComponent__c>> fieldComponent {get; set;}

public string OPPORTUNITY_STRING = 'Opportunity';
public string MAINTENANCE_PRODUCT_STRING = 'mpo';
public string WITH_PRODUCT_STRING = 'wip';
public string WITHOUT_PRODUCT_STRING = 'wop';
public string CLONE_OPTION_STRING = 'clo';
public string ID_STRING = 'id';

public static Boolean isCloned = false;

private transient Map<String,Schema.DescribeFieldResult> fieldDescribe;
private Integer dependentCount = 0;

public ApexPages.StandardController controller {get; set;}

public OpportunityCustomCloneController(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
    this.controller = controller;

    if(!Test.isRunningTest() && addFields != null) {
        controller.addFields(addFields);
    }

    oppId = controller.getId();
    opp = (Opportunity) controller.getRecord();
    recordTypeId = opp.RecordTypeID;

    cloneOption = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get(CLONE_OPTION_STRING);

    getMetadata();

    //getPageLayout();



}

private void getMetadata(){
    Map<String,Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = Schema.sObjectType.Opportunity.fields.getMap();
    fieldDescribe = new Map<String,Schema.DescribeFieldResult>();

    for(String fieldName : fieldMap.keyset()){
        fieldDescribe.put(fieldName.toLowerCase(),fieldMap.get(fieldName).getDescribe());
    }
}

public PageReference customClone() {

    //String urlRecordType = pageRecordType();
    String urlRecordType = 'OpportunityCustomCloneEdit';
    PageReference editCloneOpportunityPage = new PageReference('/apex/'+urlRecordType);
    editCloneOpportunityPage.getParameters().put(ID_STRING , opp.Id);
    editCloneOpportunityPage.getParameters().put(CLONE_OPTION_STRING , cloneOption); 
    editCloneOpportunityPage.setRedirect(true);


    return editCloneOpportunityPage; 
}

public Map<String, SObjectField> getObjectFields(String objectName) {
    SObjectType objToken = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectName); 
    DescribeSObjectResult objDef = objToken.getDescribe();
    Map<String, SObjectField> fields = objDef.fields.getMap();

    return fields;
}

public void getCloneSettings() {
    Map<String, Opportunity_Fields__c> allOpportunityFields = Opportunity_Fields__c.getAll();
    List<Opportunity_Fields__c> opportunityFields = allOpportunityFields.values();

    Map<String, SObjectField> fields = getObjectFields(OPPORTUNITY_STRING);
    if(fieldDescribe == null){
        getMetadata();
    }
    for(Opportunity_Fields__c ofs : opportunityFields){
        System.debug('* ** ** ' + ofs.API_Name__c + ' ' + ofs.To_Be_Cloned__c);
        if(ofs.To_Be_Cloned__c == null || !ofs.To_Be_Cloned__c){ 
            //SObjectField f = fields.get(ofs.API_Name__c);

            if(fieldDescribe.containsKey(ofs.API_Name__c)){
            DescribeFieldResult fr = fieldDescribe.get(ofs.API_Name__c.toLowerCase());
            //f.getDescribe();
            System.debug('* ** *** fr ' + fr);
            if(fr.isUpdateable() && fr.isAccessible()){
                opp.put(ofs.API_Name__c, NULL);
            }
            }else{
                try{
                    opp.put(ofs.API_Name__c, NULL);
                }catch(Exception e){}
            }
        }
    }
    System.debug('* ** *** opp ' + opp);
}


public PageReference customSaveAndAddProduct(){
    opp.Id = NULL; 
    opp.OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId();

    boolean hasError = false;
    try{
        //checks if the opportunity has already been cloned once during the transaction.
        if(!isCloned) {
            insert opp;
            isCloned = true;
            sendSuccessMessage(opp.Id);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        hasError = true;
        isCloned = false;
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.FATAL, e.getMessage()));
        sendErrorEmail(e.getMessage());

    }

    if(hasError){
        return null;
    }else{        
        PageReference opportunityProductSelect = new PageReference('/apex/OpportunityProductSelection');
        opportunityProductSelect.getParameters().put(ID_STRING , opp.Id);

        return opportunityProductSelect;
    }
}

public PageReference customSave() {
    List<OpportunityLineItem> oppProdList = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();

    if(cloneOption == WITH_PRODUCT_STRING || cloneOption == MAINTENANCE_PRODUCT_STRING){
        Map<String, SObjectField> oltFields = getObjectFields('OpportunityLineItem');
        String selectFields = '';
        String dbQuery = '';

        for (Schema.SObjectField ft : oltFields.values()){
           Schema.DescribeFieldResult fd = ft.getDescribe();
           if(fd.isCreateable()){
               if(selectFields == '') {
                   selectFields = fd.getName();
               } else {
                   selectFields = selectFields + ', ' + fd.getName();
               }
           }
        }

        dbQuery = 'SELECT ' + selectFields + ' FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE OpportunityId = \'' +opp.Id+ '\' AND Product2.isActive = true';

        if(cloneOption == MAINTENANCE_PRODUCT_STRING) { 
            dbQuery = dbquery + ' AND Product2.Family = \'Maintenance\'';
        }

        List<OpportunityLineItem> opportunityProducts = Database.query(dbQuery);
        for(OpportunityLineItem op : opportunityProducts){
            oppProdList.add(op.clone(false,true));
        }
    }

    opp.Id = NULL;
    opp.OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId();

    boolean hasError = false;
    try{
        //checks if the opportunity has already been cloned once during the transaction.
        if(!isCloned) {
            insert opp;
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        hasError = true;
        isCloned = false;
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.FATAL, e.getMessage()));
        sendErrorEmail(e.getMessage());
    }

    if(!hasError && !isCloned){
        if(!oppProdList.isEmpty()){
            for(OpportunityLineItem olt : oppProdList) {
                olt.OpportunityID = opp.Id;
                if(olt.UnitPrice != NULL && olt.TotalPrice != NULL) { 
                   olt.UnitPrice = NULL;
                }
            }
            try{

                insert oppProdList;
                isCloned = true;
                sendSuccessMessage(opp.Id);
            }catch(Exception e){
                hasError = true;
                isCloned = false;
                ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.FATAL, e.getMessage()));
                sendErrorEmail(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    if(hasError){
        return null;
    }else{
        return new PageReference('/'+opp.id);
    }
}

public static Boolean runningInASandbox() {
  return [SELECT Id, IsSandbox FROM Organization LIMIT 1].IsSandbox;
}




        //02-02-2017 Added IsRequired__c field
        for(LayoutComponent__c lc : [
         SELECT   ID, Name, Columns__c, IsBlank__c, IsField__c, IsSection__c, IsEditable__c,
                  Order__c, IsRequired__c, ParentComponent__c, FieldName__c,SectionName__c 
        FROM LayoutComponent__c 
        WHERE Layout__c = :layoutId AND (IsField__c = true OR IsBlank__c = true)
        ORDER BY Order__c
        ]){


            if(lc.IsField__c && !String.isBlank(lc.FieldName__c)  && 
                fieldDescribe.containsKey(lc.FieldName__c.toLowerCase()) &&
                componentMap.containsKey(lc.ParentComponent__c) 
            ){
                boolean isDependent = fieldDescribe.get(lc.FieldName__c.toLowerCase()).isDependentPicklist();
                if(isDependent){ 
                    dependentCount++;
                }

            //debugSection.childComponents.add(new Component.Apex.OutputText(value = '{!opp.' + lc.FieldName__c + '}'));

                if(lc.IsEditable__c && (!isDependent || dependentCount <= 10) ){
                    Component.Apex.InputField fieldComponent = new Component.Apex.InputField();
                    fieldComponent.expressions.value = '{!opp.' + lc.FieldName__c + '}';
                    //fieldComponent.expressions.required = '{!'+ !lc.IsRequired__c +'}';
                    componentMap.get(lc.ParentComponent__c).childComponents.add(fieldComponent);
                }else{
                    Component.Apex.OutputField fieldComponent = new Component.Apex.OutputField();
                    fieldComponent.expressions.value = '{!opp.' + lc.FieldName__c + '}';
                    componentMap.get(lc.ParentComponent__c).childComponents.add(fieldComponent);

                }

                /*Component.Apex.OutputText textComponent = new Component.Apex.OutputText();
                textComponent.value = lc.Order__c + ': ' + lc.FieldName__c;
                componentMap.get(lc.ParentComponent__c).childComponents.add(textComponent);*/

                System.debug('* ** *** adding field ' + lc.FieldName__c);

                fieldNames.add(lc.FieldName__c);
            }else if(lc.IsBlank__c){
                Component.Apex.PageBlockSectionItem blankComponent = new Component.Apex.PageBlockSectionItem();
                componentMap.get(lc.ParentComponent__c).childComponents.add(blankComponent);
            }

        }//end-for

        for(Id sectionId : sectionIds){
            dynBlock.childComponents.add(componentMap.get(sectionId));
        }

        if(!fieldNames.isEmpty()){
            for(String fieldName : fieldNames){
                if(pageLayoutFields == '') {
                    pageLayoutFields = fieldName;
                } else {
                    pageLayoutFields += ', ' + fieldName;
                }
            }

            opp = Database.query('SELECT ' + pageLayoutFields + ' FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = \'' + oppId + '\' LIMIT 1');
            getCloneSettings();
            opp.OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId();
        }
    }
    return dynBlock;
}  
}
```

while the VF Page/Javascript

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="OpportunityCustomCloneController" >
<script>
    function disableSaveButton(){
        document.getElementById("{!$Component.form.mainBlock.pageBlockButtons.saveButton}").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("{!$Component.form.mainBlock.pageBlockButtons.saveButton}").className = "btnDisabled";
        disableCancel();
    }



    function disableCancel(){
        document.getElementById("{!$Component.form.mainBlock.pageBlockButtons.cancelButton}").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("{!$Component.form.mainBlock.pageBlockButtons.cancelButton}").className = "btnDisabled";
    }

    function enableSaveButton(){
        document.getElementById("{!$Component.form.mainBlock.pageBlockButtons.saveButton}").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("{!$Component.form.mainBlock.pageBlockButtons.saveButton}").className = "btn";
        enableCancel();
    }


</script>
<apex:sectionHeader title="Opportunity Clone" subtitle="{!Opportunity.Name}"/>
<apex:form id="form">
<apex:pageMessages id="msgs" />
    <apex:dynamicComponent componentValue="{!DynamicBlock}" />
    <apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity.RecordTypeID}" rendered="false"/>
</apex:form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have two buttons and want to disable both when processing.

You have not added code for second button, so wrote a small page which disables both buttons on click. It has a common function **toggleButtons** to enable or disable buttons.

Check if you find it useful.

Page:

```
<apex:page controller="DynamicApex" id="page">
    <apex:sectionHeader title="Force.com" subTitle="Dynamic Component Sample" />
    <apex:form id="form">
        <apex:pageMessages id="msg"/>
        <apex:dynamicComponent componentValue="{!DynamicPageBlock}"/>
    </apex:form>
    <script>
        function disableButtons() {
            toggleButtons("{!$Component.form.accountPageBlock.buttonBlocks.firstButton}", true);
            toggleButtons("{!$Component.form.accountPageBlock.buttonBlocks.secondButton}", true);
        }
        function enableButtons() {
            toggleButtons("{!$Component.form.accountPageBlock.buttonBlocks.firstButton}", false);
            toggleButtons("{!$Component.form.accountPageBlock.buttonBlocks.secondButton}", false);
        }

        function toggleButtons(elementId, disableButton) {

            document.getElementById(elementId).disabled = disableButton;
            document.getElementById(elementId).className = 
                disableButton == true ? "btnDisabled" : "btn";
        }
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Class:

```
public class DynamicApex{

    public Account account {get; set;}

    public DynamicApex() {
        this.account = new Account();
    }

    public Component.Apex.PageBlock getDynamicPageBlock() {

        // PageBlock
        Component.Apex.PageBlock dynamicPageBlock = new Component.Apex.PageBlock(
            title    = 'Account Block'
            ,id       = 'accountPageBlock'
            ,mode     = 'edit'
            ,tabStyle = 'Account'
        );

        // Add PageBlockButtons
        Component.Apex.PageBlockButtons dynamicPageBlockButtons = 
            new Component.Apex.PageBlockButtons(
                location = 'bottom',
                id = 'buttonBlocks'
            );
        dynamicPageBlock.childComponents.add(dynamicPageBlockButtons);

        // Add First CommandButton
        Component.Apex.CommandButton button = new Component.Apex.CommandButton();
        button.value = 'First Button';
        button.expressions.action = '{!doNothing}';
        button.onclick = 'disableButtons();';
        button.id = 'firstButton';

        button.rerender = new Set<String>{'msg'};      
        dynamicPageBlockButtons.childComponents.add(button);

        // Add Second CommandButton
        button = new Component.Apex.CommandButton();
        button.value = 'Second Button';
        button.expressions.action = '{!doNothing}';
        button.onclick = 'disableButtons();';
        button.id = 'secondButton';

        button.rerender = new Set<String>{'msg'};   

        // Add Third CommandButton
        button = new Component.Apex.CommandButton();
        button.value = 'Enable both';
        button.expressions.action = '{!doNothing}';
        button.onclick = 'enableButtons();';
        button.id = 'secondButton';

        button.rerender = new Set<String>{'msg'};   

        dynamicPageBlockButtons.childComponents.add(button);

        return dynamicPageBlock;
    }

    public void doNothing() {
    }
}
```

Comment: ahh, gotcha. try using to find elements by class instead of an Id

Comment: Instead of getElementById, you can use [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) to get list of elements, its JavaScript not Salesforce.